# How to disable Google translate for HTML Class names

Tags: html, knockout.js, google-translate

I'm running through to ignoring html class name translation. I'm finding out the following solution

```
<span class="notranslate">this text will not be translated</span>
```

But I want to ignore my HTML Class name to be ignored instead of text.

```
Example:
 <div data-bind="attr : { 'class':'notranslate '+headerLabel()}">
Result:
 <div class="notranslate classname">
```

In the following example **I do not want to translate my dynamic classname.**
Anyone help me to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

Add this line to your code for disable the whole google translate in your webpage.

`<html translate="no">`

Comment: Already tried. Not working.